# Weird error with training custom images with Xception CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a series of small images and would like to run the training of an XCeption CNN using them. The training and validation set have, respectively the following shape:

```
>(63787, 72, 72, 3) 

>(155, 72, 72, 3)
```

In other words, my images fulfill the Xception requirements of the 71,71,3 minimum shape for Xceptions input.

This is the way I build the model

```
    base_model=xception.Xception(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(72, 72, 3))
    x = base_model.output
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    predictions = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    opt= SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

This is the way I train the model

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='max', period=self.__model_history_period)
lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=np.sqrt(0.1), cooldown=0, patience=1000, min_lr=0.5e-6)
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.0001, patience=10000)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, lr_reducer, early_stopper]

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True) 
datagen.fit(x_train)
 # Fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow().
H=model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train,batch_size=self.__bs), steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // self.__bs, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=self.__epochs, verbose=1, max_q_size=100, callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_reducer, early_stopper])
```

However, when I run the CNN training, I have the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esperimento_paper.py", line 86, in <module>
    vgg.run_2D()
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/src/classes/VggHandler.py", line 662, in run_2D
    model, H, n_epochs = self.__train_2D(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train, x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, index_net=index_net, index_walk=index_walk)
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/src/classes/VggHandler.py", line 267, in __train_2D
    callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_reducer, early_stopper])  
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 144, in fit_generator
    val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "Desktop/PhD-Market-Nets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (155, 1)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
x = base_model.output
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
```

As you set `include_top=False` - then what is returned is a feature map of shape `[number of examples, h, w, number of features]`. When you apply a `Dense` to this feature map - you are applying it to only last dimension (it is similar to 1x1 convolutions). This is why the output is `4D`. In order to overcome this try:

```
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
```

`Flatten` will squash `h`, `w` and `number of features` dimension to a single dimension. Thanks to that your network should work fine.

PS. You can also try to use [`GlobalMaxPooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling2d) or its average version. This would skip the spatial position of filters but will decrease the memory footpring of a model by a significant factor.

Comment: I wish I could hug you to thank you! It worked! thanks!